# exe file made by pyinstaller has problem executing

Tags: python, pyinstaller, file-not-found, build-error, summarization

Here is python script:

[image]

I used Visual Studio Code to run the file with this command:

[image]

And I get desired result:

[image]

Now I tried to create .exe file by opening PowerShell in the folder where is my script and
running next line:

[image]

Here is stuff I got(not including otherScripts folder):

[image]

Now I open CMD, navigate to the desired folder, and run the .exe file with the next lines of code:

[image]

Here is what I get as my first warning:

[image]

And here is what I get as a Traceback(console instantly closed and I could not use the snipping tool to capture what was an error, so I run it through C# Win Form application and redirected standard error to a label in form):

[image]

I tried:

1. pip install transformers -U.
2. instead of --onefile, use command --onedir
3. line 3 (import tqdm) in the script, was recently added to try to fix the error. Because it says that "tqdm was not found and is required by the application.", so I just put it there.
4. Updating pyinstaller and transformers to the latest versions.
5. Other stuff I don't remember right now.

None of these things worked. And I'm kinda stuck here.
I would really appreciate any help to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2):

for me adding the "tqdm directories" to datas solved the problem :)

In *script*.spec:

```
datas=[
('C:\\<...>\\Lib\\site-packages\\tqdm', 'tqdm\\'),
('C:\\<...>\\Lib\\site-packages\\tqdm-4.50.2.dist-info', 'tqdm-4.50.2.dist-info\\'),
...],
```

Comment: Ah and the problems just started there! ... Had to add about 10 - 15 more packages that way...

Comment: Well. I actually got it working using some other python library.
I kind of wasted a lot of time trying to fix something that I don't really know much about.
So I just used another solution for summarization.

Comment: Library used was gensim.

Comment: I am using transformer for translation (MarianMT) :)

Answer (score 1):

Try building with `--exclude-module=torch`?(Taken from: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4695)

Comment: Hello, and thanks for your reply.
That only fixed WARNING: "File already exists, but should not." 

After Traceback(Most recent call last), everything was the same.

Comment: How did you install TDQM? Using pip or Python?

Comment: I think I installed it using pip. I just tried now in cmd, I wrote: pip install tdqm
and it said that Requirement is satisfied: tqdm in C:\...

Comment: Try using  `python -m pip install tqdm ` and then `python -c 'import tqdm'` (Taken from: https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/497)

Comment: On the first line: python -m pip install tqdm, I get a reply that Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in c:\...
On the second line: python -c 'import tqdm' , I get a replay that:
File "<string>", line 1
  'import
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal.
Im pretty sure i typed the way you wrote:

python -c 'import tqdm'

Comment: Try Uninstalling TQDM and reinstall it using the command, as for the second error, i´ll look into it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230380/discussion-between-chindamay-and-nikola-bozin).

Comment: Any resolution to this issue in chat?

Comment: No, but the answer beneath this does have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Running `python3 -m pip install tqdm` solved the problem.